# Doing something only if there is little room left on the current line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Say we wish to set attributions flush right and on the same line if
there is ample room (at least 2em extra).  If there is not, they should be set on the next
line, also flush right.  How would one write a macro `\whence` that
took care of that?  My attempt below is not able to figure out whether
or not there is room and requires a manual `\\`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{showframe}

    \textwidth=1.5in

    \newcommand\whence[1]{\unskip\mbox{}\hskip2em\hfill#1}

    \begin{document}

    % attribution to the right, same line
    all is water
    \whence{thales}

    % no room!
    sum res cogitans
    \whence{descartes}

    % take new line
    sum res cogitans\\
    \whence{descartes}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the [attrib](https://ctan.org/pkg/attrib) package could be of use here? It apparently not only works with block environments and may be tweaked to fit your purpose (minimum distance to text, appearance of attribution).

Answer (score 3):

The [linegoal](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) package provides `\linegoal`, the remaining length of the line. Comparing the width of the stuff to be placed in the remaining line (via `\settowidth`) with the remaining length of the line can decide whether a line break is needed. (I do not think the 2em-rule is necessary, but implemented it anyway.) Instead of `text\whence{ text}` you can also use `text \whence{text}`, just be sure to not get `texttext` as output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{linegoal}
\newdimen\remaininglength
\newlength\stuffwidth

\textwidth=1.5in

\newcommand\whence[1]{%
\setlength\remaininglength\linegoal%
\settowidth\stuffwidth{#1}%
\ifdim\stuffwidth<2em\relax%
  \setlength\stuffwidth{2em}%
\fi%
\ifdim\stuffwidth>\remaininglength\relax%
  \\ \unskip\mbox{}\hskip2em\hfill#1%
\else%
  \unskip\mbox{}\hskip2em\hfill#1%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}

% attribution to the right, same line
all is water\whence{ thales}

% no room!
sum res cogitans\whence{ descartes}

% take new line
sum res cogitans\\
\whence{ descartes}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by the following macro:

```
\def\whence #1\par{\unskip 
  \nobreak\hfill\penalty71\hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill \hbox{#1}\par}
```

If the whence text cannot fit to the same line, then the line is broken at `\penalty71`. The previous line have `\nobreak\hfill` to fill the space and the next line have `\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill \hbox{text}`. This shifts the text to the right margin because `\parfillskip` is only `\hfil` (with one el, no double el).

If the whence text +2em fits to the same line, this line have

```
\nobreak\hfill\penalty71\hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\hbox{text}
```

and this shifts the text to the right margin because there are two `\hfill`s here.

Comment: Of course you know where the code comes from. Why not tell?

Comment: Petr Olsak: TeXbook naruby, page 212, lines of code #6--8, http://petr.olsak.net/tbn.html

Comment: That's clearly borrowed from the TeXbook. And it lacks an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class has a `\sourceatright[<length>]{<text>}` which when used will typeset `<text>` flushright if there is enough space left on the line, otherwise typesets it flushright on the next line. The optional `<space>` (default 2em) is the space minimal space before `<text>`. If I remember correctly it is based on code from Knuth's *The TeXbook*. It is a working equivalent of your `\whence`.

```
% whenceprob.tex  SE 586319
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{showframe}

    \textwidth=1.5in

%    \newcommand\whence[1]{\unskip\mbox{}\hskip2em\hfill#1}
%  from the memoir class
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sourceatright}[2][2em]{{%
  \unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip#1\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil{#2}
  \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits=0\par}}
\makeatother

\let\whence\sourceatright

    \begin{document}

    % attribution to the right, same line
    all is water
    \whence{thales}

    % no room!
    sum res cogitans
    \whence{descartes}

    % take new line
    sum res cogitans\\
    \whence{descartes}

    \end{document}
```

[image]